# android studio with sqlite error

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write an app with a SQLite database in android studio. One column of the database table should read out in a spinner. But when I try to start the activity with the spinner, the app crashes with the following error:

> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                                                       Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                                                           (near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Gruppe ,  FROM Kunden_list)

Here the code of one of my classes. I think the error is in this class or do I am wrong?

```
package com.example.katjarummler.hundeschule_petra_bennemann;



import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HundeschuleMemoDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String LOG_TAG =             
HundeschuleMemoDBHelper.class.getSimpleName();



public static final String DB_NAME = "Kunden_list.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 6;

public static final String TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST = "Kunden_list";


public  static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public  static final  String COLUMN_KName = "Name";
public  static final String COLUMN_GNAME = "Gruppe";
public  static final String COLUMN_KTELEFON = "Telefon";
public  static final String COLUMN_HUND = "Hund";
public  static final String COLUMN_BEGINN = "Beginn";
public  static final String COLUMN_CHECKED = "checked";



public  static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + 
TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST +
        "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_KName + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_GNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_KTELEFON + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_HUND + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_BEGINN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COLUMN_CHECKED + " BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";


public  static final String SQL_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + 
TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST;



public HundeschuleMemoDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DBHelper hat die Datenbank: " + getDatabaseName() + 
" erzeugt.");
}



//Die onCreate-Methode wird nur aufgerufen, falls die Datenbank noch 
nicht existiert
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Die Tabelle wird mit SQL-Befehl: " + SQL_CREATE 
+ " angelegt.");
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Fehler beim Anlegen der Tabelle: " +     
ex.getMessage());
    }

}


// Die onUpgrade-Methode wird aufgerufen, sobald die neue 
Versionsnummer höher
// als die alte Versionsnummer ist und somit ein Upgrade notwendig wird

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
newVersion) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Die Tabelle mit Versionsnummer " + oldVersion + " 
wird entfernt.");
    db.execSQL(SQL_DROP);

    onCreate(db);
}


public List<HundeschuleMemoKunden> getAll(){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " +
            COLUMN_GNAME + " , " +
            " FROM " + TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST;

    List<HundeschuleMemoKunden> gruppenList = new 
ArrayList<HundeschuleMemoKunden>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);  //The mark 
of the error is here

    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            HundeschuleMemoKunden gruppe = new 
HundeschuleMemoKunden("kName", "gName", "kTelefon", "hName", "beginn");

 gruppe.setgName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
(this.COLUMN_GNAME))
);
            gruppenList.add(gruppe);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return gruppenList;
}



}
```

Comment: Your select query is wrong. You have most probably missed a column after the `" , "`-comma before `FROM`.

Answer (score 1):

error is in you getAll() Method as stated by the error detail:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " +
        COLUMN_GNAME + " , " +
        " FROM " + TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST;
```

Syntax error in you SELECT query, the comma beside FROM. Change to:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " +
    COLUMN_GNAME +
    " FROM " + TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + 
TABLE_KUNDEN_LIST +
    "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    COLUMN_KName + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COLUMN_GNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COLUMN_KTELEFON + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COLUMN_HUND + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COLUMN_BEGINN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COLUMN_CHECKED + " BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
```

BOOLEAN doesn't exist in sqlite, it should be an Integer column where parsing it is:

```
//value is 1 then true else false
value > 0 ? true : false
```

and inserting should be

```
 //value is true = 1 else 0
value ? 1 : 0
```

Odds are the table isn't creating properly if that is accurate.
Also remove the comma from your select statement. Also don't do raw queries, you should become versed in the database.query, database.insert, database.delete, and so on.